# Which clipboard is used when Autokey copies and pastes

Tags: python, macros, xorg

Using in Linux Mint 19.1 (2nd release) Cinnamon and Autokey 95.7 (Python 3) on a dual boot Windows desktop.

The Autokey function "*variable*=clipboard.get_selection()" does not store the selected text in X Windows. This is obvious when one looks for the text in X clipboard viewers. Where is it stored?

Comment: Pure guess, cos I'm on Mac not nix - the [kill ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut%2C_copy%2C_and_paste)? Try ctrl/k to kill [cut], ctrl/y to yank [paste]

Answer (score 1):

As far as Autokey-gtk is concerned, I use their python3 based code to enforce focus in instances where the "Select all" is required. Otherwise, their code works as expected, by copying selected text.

For me, this was caused the Linux Mint Cinnamon Windows behavior settings. They did not seem to communicate with X-Clipboard properly to focus, when the pointer was placed in a particular window. Even when a single window was left open, after manually closing other windows. This seemed odd compared to previous versions. Now, I select "Click" exclusively, and the focus of this setting is improved.

Watched what various apps see on X-clipboard's,**Clipboard** and **Primary** storage areas by using Diodon, and then Parcellite to confirm my understanding of clipboard viewers and what options are available beyond their default settings. Default options of both viewers are the best.